# How can i solve this on VC++ 6.0

Tags: c++

i've this simple code but i dont where is the error of this all

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    cout<<"Entrer nom de fichier avec le source";
    cin s;
    ifstream fout;
    fout.open(s);
    s=fout.getche();
    fout.close();
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

cause the errors showing after compiling are:

```
d:\workespace3.cpp(5) : error C2871: 'std' : does not exist or is not a namespace

d:\workespace3.cpp(8) : error C2653: 'std' : is not a class or namespace name

d:\workespace3.cpp(8) : error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier

d:\workespace3.cpp(8) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 's'

d:\workespace3.cpp(8) : error C2065: 's' : undeclared identifier

d:\workespace3.cpp(10) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 's'

d:\workespace3.cpp(13) : error C2039: 'getche' : is not a member of 'ifstream'

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\fstream.h(98) : see declaration of 'ifstream'
Error executing cl.exe.

workespace3.obj - 7 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: You want to include `<iostream>` and `<string>` and not the includes you have now.  And also get a decent intro book to C++.  Also, VC++ 6.0 is a horrible compiler and violates a number of standards.  I strongly suggest using something from the last decade if possible.

Comment: @Joe: To be fair, it doesn't "violate" C++98 and later standards, it just predates them. But that's also a good reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `.h` forms of the include files, those are meant for backwards compatibility with C. Use for example `#include <string>`.

Comment: @user3075420, happy birthday? Why do you say that? And you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have many errors:

1- You are using deprecated header files. Standard C++ library headers come in headers without ".h". So that would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

2- getche() is not a proper method of ifstream. Here is the complete list of methods of ifstream:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

You probably meant to use get() or getline()

3- You are missing "­­>>" between "cin" and "s".

4- You are using a very old IDE. There are multiple newer and free IDEs out there. Notably you can have VC++ 2012 Express for free. It will be more standards compliant and also include better tools and support for C++11

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler supports the C++98 standard headers, then use them

```
#include <iostream> // no .h
```

If it only supports the ancient pre-ISO headers that you're including, then just leave out any mention of `namespace std`. In those dark days, the standard library was just dumped into the global namespace.

I would consider using a compiler from this millennium; you'll find it easier to get help from people whose memory of the 1990s is less than perfect.

Comment: I have just tested this and the C++98 standard headers work with Visual C++ 6. I was not sure myself since VC++ 6 was released in 1998 (and I have not used it in many years). Although I do have SP5 (service pack) I believe.